# UniversaIimageLoader not work well with viewflow: ImageView not as expacted

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader, viewflow

Working with [IUL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is OK.
Working with [ViewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) is also OK.
while use these two together there is problem. **The ImageView show different faces for the same URI picture!**
For Detail:  
Bitmap from cache is different from bitmap from Net.  I have [a test project](https://github.com/acntwww/ViewFlowAndIUL2) show this problem for detail. In order to see the same, you should click->Next-->beck menu -->next .

Any one can help?

Comment: Try to use AndroidQuery instead of Universal ImageLoader : http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: Aren't you forgetting `cacheInMemory(true)` and `cacheOnDisk(true)` on your `ImageLoaderConfiguration`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira Not really, I have add these options to MY DisplayImageOptions

Comment: @HareshChhelana This wont work for ViewFlow, Any Tips?